# Copying data of only few columns to one more data table

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, ado.net

I have a scenario where I get a data table with 65 columns and 100 rows. I need to create one more data table with all 100 rows, i.e. the same as the original data table but should be having only 5 columns out of 65 present in original table. Is there any way to achieve this without looping?

Comment: wht r the columns do u want to retain? The first five or the last five or the selected five columns? Mention it clearly.

Comment: @ thevan I have some selected column

Comment: Hi Satyajit. I edited my answer. It will give the final solution to ur Question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try [DataView.ToTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx) method.

Use it like this:

```
DataTable newTable = oldTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "ColumnName1", "ColumnName2", "ColumnName3", "ColumnName4", "ColumnName5");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DataTable oldTable = new DataTable();
DataTable newTable = oldTable.Copy();
for (int i = 5; i < 65; i++)
{
    newTable.Columns.RemoveAt(i);   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
DataTable newTable  = oldTable.Copy();
newTable.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");
```

You remove the unwanted columns here.

Here is the best Solution for your Question:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string [] column = {"Column1", "Column2"};
dt = DTItem.DefaultView.ToTable("dd", false, column);      
//DTItem is the Existing  Table and "dd" is the temporary tablename, u give whatever u want
```

Answer (score 1):

lets assume we want to create a new datatable and grab first four columns of an existing datatable and put it in new datatable.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable destiny = new DataTable();
        destiny.Columns.Add("c1");//set the columns you want to copy
        destiny.Columns.Add("c2");
        destiny.Columns.Add("c3");
        destiny.Columns.Add("c4");

        CopyColumns(dtST_Split, destiny, "c1", "c2","c3","c4");

    }
// function to copy all rows but just specific columns from table 1 to table 2
    private void CopyColumns(DataTable source, DataTable dest, params string[] columns)
    {
        foreach (DataRow sourcerow in source.Rows)
        {
            DataRow destRow = dest.NewRow();
            foreach (string colname in columns)
            {
                destRow[colname] = sourcerow[colname];
            }
            dest.Rows.Add(destRow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some context to your answer?

Comment: I thought the code is clear enough to explain what it does.  but I add  some line into it to make it more clear