# Remove group by from LINQ QUERY

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I want to remove GROUP BY clause from the below code. How could i do this.

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("BATCH NUM"))
              .Select(g =>
              {
                  var row = dt.NewRow();

                  row["BATCH NUM"] = g.Key;
                  row["QTY"] = g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("QTY")) + Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("BONUS")));
                  row["PROD ID"] = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("PROD ID")).Distinct());
                  // row["PROD ID"] = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("PROD ID"));
                  return row;
              }).CopyToDataTable();
```

It creates problem, when we have two Different "PROD ID" but with same "BATCH NUM"then it combines "PROD ID" into a single field it treats both PROD ID with same batch. [Here is a Image you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYSfH.jpg)

Result which i want is like below.

Comment: Remove the `GroupBy` so what result you expect?

Comment: When i remove group by clause it gves me cannot resolve reference error.

Comment: Put the marker next to `.GroupBy`, press delete key. Done - removed from code.

Comment: Basically i dont want to group rows, and i want to copy values of only those 3 columns which you can see.

Comment: @mrjahanzaibniazi: then edit your question and explain it

Comment: The this is different question and the answer can be found here: [Copying data of only few columns to one more data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183621/copying-data-of-only-few-columns-to-one-more-data-table/6183839#6183839)

Comment: i have edited my question and aded more details with image please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to delete the Group By it give you an error becouse you do a Sum in the select. The object that you "GROUP" is not longer a Set of TKey, TElement when you delete it.

If you want to do a Sum of "QTY" of each "PROD ID" and collect the "BATCH NUM", that is the best way.

There is another way using a ToLookup but:
[lookup vs. groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739462/lookup-vs-groupby)

> Details asked in comments:

With the lookup you can do the same thing...

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
.ToLookup(r => r.Field<string>("PROD ID"))
.Select(g =>
{
     var row = dt.NewRow();
     row["PROD ID"] = g.Key;
     row["QTY"] = g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("QTY")) + Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("BONUS")));
     row["BATCH NUM"] = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("BATCH NUM")));
     return row;
}).CopyToDataTable();
```

Is quite the same thing, the difference is in the post that i linked below.

Comment: Yes you are right error is in Sum. So how to apply lookup in it. ?

Comment: No, it is not working it is also grouping. Lets say when we have two different BATCH NUM but same product id's it sums their QTY and add "BATCH NUM" in a single field.

Comment: i have edited my question and added more details with image please have a look on it

Comment: Ahhh. Becouse you need to group the Batch number too. Like -> GroupBy(r => { r.Field<string>("BATCH NUM"), r.Field<string>("BATCH NUM")})