# C# - Excel Export a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi i have this code To export a List to An Excel:

```
private DataTable ListaDatiReportQuietanzamento(List<DatiReportQuietanzamento> datiReportQuietanzamento)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("DatiReportQuietanzamento");
    dt.Columns.Add("Polizza");
    dt.Columns.Add("Posizione");
    dt.Columns.Add("Codice Frazionamento");

    var result = datiReportQuietanzamento.ToDataTable().AsEnumerable().Select(p =>
        new
        {
            n_polizza = p.Field<long>("n_polizza"),
            n_posizione = p.Field<byte>("n_posizione"),
            c_frazionamento = p.Field<string>("c_frazionamento")
        }).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item.n_polizza, item.n_posizione, item.c_frazionamento);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

This method works with Lists that does not contain many items , but when the list is very large , the method takes too many time.

There is a way to avoid the foreach and add to the rows the items directly? Maybe with Lambda Expression?

Thank you.

Comment: For starters you can avoid `datiReportQuietanzamento.ToDataTable().AsEnumerable()` and direactly do `datiReportQuietanzamento.Select()`. Also avoid `.ToList()`

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6183839/643104) is how you can fill one datatable with other datatable using selected columns

Comment: [Returning datatable using entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614944/205233) might also help.

Comment: I removed the tsql tag since you are using EntityFramework. If you actually want to use an SQL query there's an answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

While you have not specified how the data is ultimately to be supplied to Excel, generally it is supplied a CSV ([Comma Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) file for easy import.

So this being the case you can eliminate your data table conversion entirely and create a list of strings as follows:

```
private List<string> ListaDatiReportQuietanzamento(List<DatiReportQuietanzamento> datiReportQuietanzamento)
{
     var result = new List<string>();
     foreach (var item in datiReportQuietanzamento)
     {
        result.AppendLine($"{item.n_polizza},{item.n_posizione},{item.c_frazionamento}");
     }

    return result;
}
```

Now the only simplification I have made is not to worry about encoding because strings should actually be escaped so `item.c_frazionamento` should actually be escaped.

Instead of doing this all yourself, I suggest you have a look at a NuGet package such as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which will help you with creating CSV files and take all the hassle with escaping things out of the equation. It can also directly deal with a list of objects and convert it into a CSV file for you see specifically the first example in https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/writing#writing-all-records