# How to constraint 2 DataTable columns name

Tags: c#, datatable

I look for a simplest way to constraint two DataTable´s on columns names...

here my code:

```
DataTable productsAllColums = ....;
DataTable productsJustColumnsToView = ...;
// they both imported from db and both have same stucture

                for (int i = 0; i < productsAllColums.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < productsJustColumnsToView.Columns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        if (productsAllColums.Columns[i].ColumnName == productsJustColumnsToView.Columns[k].ColumnName)
                            break;
                        else
                            productsAllColums.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
```

This solution doesn´t really work...

**UPDATE** more example:

DataTable productsAllColums have columns (names): col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 .... ab to col60

DataTable productsJustColumnsToView have (names) col3, col 14, col22

ALL my data are already in productsAllColums so my Idea... just delete the column they the customer don´t like to see ;-)

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do "This solution don´t really working..." isn't helpful

Comment: `constraint two DataTable´s on columns names...` what does it mean? What does it mean by `not working`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It seems like you try to remove all columns from productsAllColums that exists in productsJustColumnsToView, but you state that `they both imported from db and both have same stucture`.

Comment: 1. `both have same structure` and you trying to remove unmatched columns. So do they really have same structure then? 2. You removing column while iterating through them. After you remove column productsAllColums.Column.Count will change! 3. Your loop logic is incorrect.(if you trying to do what I imagine)

Comment: I have two DataTables 
- the first one will be read from the DB
- the second one is create from costumer choice... witch columns have to be see be view(later in DataGrid)

So the question is how I can (on simplistic way) delete that column they don´t come to view 

Sorry for my English :-D

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Copying data of only few columns to one more data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183621/copying-data-of-only-few-columns-to-one-more-data-table/6183839#6183839). You might do something like this: `productsAllColums = productsAllColums.DefaultView.ToTable(false, listOfColumnNamesFromproductsJustColumnsToView);`

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense. Are you saying you want to display the values in `productsAllColums`, but only where columns match `productsJustColumnsToView`?

Comment: hi Reniuz! Your Idea will be great BUT the compiler show me error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'string'

Comment: Dear Sean T - why it doesn´t make sense? 
My App read (example) products table from DB. But this Table have over 60 columns. So now the User can choice... I want to see just: name, price, stocknumber or what ever...

So sorry what here doesn´t make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

To have table with limited columns you can use [DataView.ToTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.
But if you don't need other data maybe it is worth refactoring not to select them in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution now:

```
DataTable productsAllColums = ....;
DataTable productsJustColumnsToView = ...;

bool columnOK;

for (int i = productsAllColums.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    columnOK = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < productsJustColumnsToView.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        if (productsAllColums.Columns[i].ColumnName == productsJustColumnsToView.Columns[k].ColumnName)
        {
            columnOK = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!columnOK)
        productsAllColums.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

I really hope for a more elegant solution ... but now that works very well too :-)